# JSF2 InputText for Long value also takes string

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have an p:inputText field in my JSF 2 form which is mapped to a

```
HashMap<String, Long>
```

values like this:

```
<p:inputText id="input1" value="#{simpleFormTest.longValues['input1']}" />
```

Now, when I submit a string value in that input text and iterate through my map of Long objects, I can see the string value there. There is no conversion exception ond classCastException. When I submit the form once more I get an exception NumberFormatException. when converting the value. It is interesting that the conversion where I get the exception happens when reading the old value from the map, not when trying to set the new one. Does anyone no, if this is some bug in JSF, or how to avoid it? I've found out that when I explicitelly set the LongConverter for that field it is working, but shouldn't this be done implicitely? Thanks.

Here is a simple test:

SimpleFormTest.java

```
@Named("simpleFormTest")
@ConversationScoped
public class SimpleFormTest implements Serializable {
    private Map<String, Long> longs = new HashMap<String, Long>();

    public String submitAction() {
        log.info("(Long): " + longs.get("test"));
    }

    public Map<String, Long> getLongs() {
        return longs;
    }

    public void setLongs(Map<String, Long> longs) {
        this.longs = longs;
    }
}
```

layout.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="new-form">
    <p:inputText value="#{simpleFormTest.longs['test']}" />
    <p:commandButton action="#{simpleFormTest.submitAction}"
</h:form>
```

If I submit the form I get following log message:

```
[com.example.SimpleFormTest] (default task-15) (Long): aa
```

Comment: You are expecting JSF to know that it should be a Long based on the generic type data. That is asking too much, that information doesn't exist at runtime. Yes, you should explicitly provide a converter IMO. I post this as a comment because I'm only 99% sure I'm speaking the truth ;)

Comment: But the value is saved in the map with long values. Why there is no ClassCastException or something like that? For Java Basic types this should be implicit, or not?

Comment: It is not a basic type, you are mapping to an Object in a HashMap.

Comment: In Java, a `String` value can't be saved in your map the way you have it declared. That's not possible. Can you provide a test case of what do you input exactly and what is stored in the map?

Comment: use `<f:validateLongValue/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At runtime, java discards all class information for generic classes (and thus, for maps). Internally, it then is just working with Objects. 
When you map a `<h:inputText>` to a Long field of a bean, this information is still present at runtime. When using a Map<..., Long> however, JSF doesn't know what to map the String (the basic type of a `<h:textInput>`) to, so it stores it as a String.

One solution is, as @Gimby proposed in the comment, to build a simple converter and force JSF to store the value as a Long.

```
@FacesConverter("longConverter")
public class FacesLongConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        return Long.parseLong(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return ((Long) value).toString();
    }

}
```

then use the converter in your JSF

```
<h:inputText
  converter="longConverter"
  value="#{simpleFormTest.longs[input1]}"/>
```

I did not see any further into the matter, **there may be more simple solutions**.